# window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL gives error code 1 after updating cordova to 10.0.0 and android to 9.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer

The code works fine in `android@8.0.0` but when I updated my cordova to `10.0.0` and cordova platform android to `9.0.0` it give error `code:1`.

Here is my code, I am using `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, //my path is file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/
    function (fileSystem) { 
                                                                      
    },function (err) {
      console.log(err); //gives error code 1
    }
```